# Excluding unique instances within a duplicate count

Tags: excel, duplicates

I've been able to find how to count duplicates, but I want to take it a step further.  Right now I have a roster of players in a game, I want to count how many Alts each person has.  So for example:

```
Name | Rank
Jim  |  12
Steve|  15
Josh |  25
Jim  |  05
Josh |  02
Kim  |  22
Steve|  02
Adam |  05
Josh |  01
```

So basic enough, but it gets the point across.  Right now if I try to find duplicates I would get the number "7" because Jim is there 2 times, Josh is there 3 times, and steve is there 2 times.  However, I just want to count how many alts there are, not duplicates.  So the first instance of a person should be excluded from the count.  So jim has 1 alt, josh has 2 alts, steve has 1 alt.  Is there any way to do this?  Maybe count how many duplicates there are, then count how many unique instances there are within the duplicates then subtract that from the total number?  Anyone know how I could do this?  That way, instead of getting 7 alts (which isn't true) I would  get 4 (because 3 of the duplicates are their main characters).  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Using your provided sample data, if the names start in A2 and go to A10, the formula would be:

```
=COUNTA(A2:A10)-SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10<>"")/COUNTIF(A2:A10,A2:A10&""))
```

To give a result of: 4